# It is possible to create a custom bundle name for swift project?

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle

My company seperate app to a miniapp but have a problem with bundle id. I want to know, Can we change a name of bundle not use "nil" or "self" ?

Example code when require bundle name

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: I dont know exactly what you want. But I have used something like this.                        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "StoryBoardName", bundle: Bundle.main)
 let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdentifierName")

Comment: plz write in detail what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a bundle for a class, by identifier or path.. and then implement it in your UIStoryboard init:

get bundler by class:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: YouViewController.self))
```

get bundler by identifier:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(identifier: "yourIdentifier")
```

get main bundler:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

I hope this solves your problem